# Uploading a video to youtube from browser

Tags: javascript, upload, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Im OK authorized.

I have 2 button's like this on my page:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToSend"/>
<input type="button" onclick="upload()" value="Upload" id="btnSend"/>
```

I want to upload the selected file to youtube when I click the "Upload" button. Im calling a function like this:

```
function upload() {
    var fileStream;
    var video = document.getElementById("fileToSend");
    var file = video.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    console.log("Nombre: " + file.name);
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function () {
        console.log("fileStream creado");
        fileStream = r.result;
        //console.log("FileStream: " + fileStream);
    };

    console.log("Creando fileStream..");
    r.readAsBinaryString(file);


    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3',
        function() {
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
                part: 'snippet, status',
                resource: {
                    snippet: {
                        title: 'Video Test Title 5',
                        description: 'Video Test Description',
                        tags: ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2'],
                        categoryId: "22"
                    },
                    status: {
                        privacyStatus: "private"
                    }
                }
            }, fileStream);
            request.execute(function (response) {
                console.log("executing..");
                var result = response.result;
                console.log(response);
                if (result) {
                    console.log("execute completed");
                    document.write(result);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

The problem is I get al error on the response object, "mediaBodyRequired", It's like I'm not sending the fileStream correctly.

Comment: You find the problem?
If so, share your complete code because that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I get error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined." why?

Comment: I ended up using the v2 API. If I find a solution using v3 I will post it.

Comment: shouldn't the gapi call be done in the onload function of the media ? Else the fileStream is not necessary all loaded and the youtube API does not like that.

Comment: Move the `gapi.client.load()` call to inside the `r.onload = function () {` block, as dievardump said.  It should either work or get you one step closer.

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason you can't just use the YouTube upload widget?
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget

Anyways, straight from the API reference 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

```
badRequest  mediaBodyRequired   The request does not include the video content.
```

Another resource:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples

Comment: Kat, thanks for your reply. I know the error is because the request doesn't include the video content, but the reason of this is that the API doesn't specify how to make insert API calls using javascipt. An example would solve all my problems.

Comment: Well, here's an example of getting a playlist... looking at it might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12939702/996364  I'm looking for an 'insert' example but all I've found so far is a java example in the second link in my answer and a python example https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video which uses oauth

Comment: Yes..I inspired my code on those examples but still no luck at all..Thanks for your help.

Comment: Regarding your question why not using the YouTube upload widget. Although it states in their intro that you can upload a file, reading on in the revision history, the option to upload a file to YouTube via the YouTube Upload Widget apparently is removed

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for using v3 insert. The request must either:

1. have the media file *as* the body which precludes sending any other POST parameters, or
2. use multipart form encoding in two parts. One part is the file to upload and the other part is a file-like JSON blob that includes any parameters you want to send.

I never did get this working using the official JavaScript client, but wrote up a pretty detailed explanation of how this can work using regular XmlHttpRequest: http://lithostech.com/2013/10/upload-google-youtube-api-v3-cors/

Here's an example of the first method where the file itself is the whole request body:

```
// where videoFile is a http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
invocation.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
invocation.open('POST', "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet", true);
invocation.send(videoFile);
```

Comment: Stephen, your blog post is great, but it doesn't show the final http request ("The result is a successful upload and the request looks very much like the one generated by the ruby gem.")... :(