# How to upload videos on Angular to Youtube using Youtube API?

Tags: angular, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload a video to Youtube using the `Google API` but I can't find where I'm supposed to put the video file as a parameter.

I've tried different things but I always get the error: `"mediaBodyRequired", "The request does not include the video content."`

What I have so far is:

```js
insertVideo() {
  var filestream;
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  // Gets Blob data from the video url
  this.galleryService.getVideo(this.videoUrl)
    .subscribe(data => {
      reader.readAsDataURL(data);
  });

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    filestream = reader.result;

    gapi.client.youtube.videos
      .insert({
        part: 'snippet,status',
        resource : {
          snippet: {
            title: 'Test video',
            description: 'Testing the YouTube API',
          },
          status: {
            privacyStatus: 'private'
          }
        },

      }, filestream) // This is where it's supposed to be?
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: You're retrieving filestream asynchronously. Put your upload video method into `subscribe` method.

Comment: @MrWoGu it's not that, I've changed the code and it still shows the same error. Like it's not sending the video in the request, even though filestream is not empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but checking [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890408/uploading-a-video-to-youtube-from-browser) and the API documentation it seems that filestream needs to come from a file upload component in your page.

Comment: @Gimby Thank you, that seems to be the same problem. I've tried reading the file but still no luck.

Comment: If anyone ends up here with the same problem, I had to give up and use PHP.