# How the find the next video uploaded by a Youtube channel

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to write a program in Javascript which, given the ID of a Youtube video, will return the ID of the next video uploaded by that channel (or user).

I've been looking through both version 2 and 3 of the API without much luck. There is the facility to search for videos matching some parameters, but not in a way which would find what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps, Get the channel ID, List it's videos, Get the next video from the "publishedAt" field. Refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930200/youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos

Comment: That would work. But with some channels having over 15,000+ videos, is this method practical?