# How to get my uploaded video list in YouTube API V3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am using url .....

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&key=[API_KEY]
```

its giving me the mostPopular video lists

but what I am trying to do is, I'm trying to get the list of videos that I have uploaded.
How to do that and Do I need OAuth 2.0 access to get that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube API v3 - List uploaded videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930200/youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos)

Comment: @putvande already checked it .. but couldn't make it work ... :(

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504899/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-uploaded-videos-for-a-certain-channel-with-the-new-youtub?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full my uploads example in javascript: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/my_uploads.js