# How to get public video based on username

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using url
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ford/uploads?alt=json&max-results=50

its giving me the video lists,but today I'm trying to get the list of videos, I received only https://youtube.com/devicesupport.

Please suggest,how i get public video feeds based on username from youtube?

Sameek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I finally figured out that it was because the Youtube V2 API has been depricated and you are now required to use the Youtube V3 API. I have no idea how to fix your problem as the V3 API requires a key to be generated and passed as an argument in the URL.

EDIT:
Here's the URL that you need to use now
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={YOUR_USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
As you can see, it requires a key to be passed as an argument.

Comment: I have refer your suggested comments as well as follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930200/youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos