# Getting All Uploaded Videos

Tags: java, video, youtube

I need a Java method which gives me a list with all YouTube watch urls (or video ids) uploaded on my own YouTube channel. Since private and unlisted videos are supposed to be included, authentication has to be given via username and password or [`OAuth 2.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Also, I'm aware of the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) but I still don't know how this can be done. Any working code snippets e.g. no vague descriptions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930200/youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos) because it's not useful like that when it all has to be automated.

I basically need a method like this:

```
public static List<String> getAllUploadedVideos(String channelUrl)
{
    // use OAuth 2.0 to gain viewing permissions for the YouTube account
    // get all uploaded videos
}
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) one can do search queries.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. It's a place to ask people about problems encountered while writing your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static List<String> getUploadedVideoIds() throws IOException
{
    YouTube youtube;
    List<String> scopes = Lists
            .newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
    Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "myuploads");

    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY,
            credential).setApplicationName(
            "youtube-cmdline-myuploads-sample").build();

    YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list(
            "contentDetails");
    channelRequest.setMine(true);
    channelRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails,nextPageToken,pageInfo");
    ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();

    List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();

    String uploadPlaylistId = channelsList.get(0).getContentDetails()
            .getRelatedPlaylists().getUploads();

    List<PlaylistItem> playlistItemList = new ArrayList<PlaylistItem>();

    YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemRequest = youtube
            .playlistItems().list("id,contentDetails,snippet");
    playlistItemRequest.setPlaylistId(uploadPlaylistId);

    playlistItemRequest
            .setFields("items(contentDetails/videoId),nextPageToken,pageInfo");

    String nextToken = "";

    do
    {
        playlistItemRequest.setPageToken(nextToken);
        PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemResult = playlistItemRequest
                .execute();

        playlistItemList.addAll(playlistItemResult.getItems());

        nextToken = playlistItemResult.getNextPageToken();
    } while (nextToken != null);

    List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList<>();

    for (PlaylistItem playListItem : playlistItemList)
    {
        videoIds.add(playListItem.getContentDetails().getVideoId());
    }

    return videoIds;
}
```

Based on the YouTube API and the [sample code](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/MyUploads.java) by Jeremy Walker.